# Maven, adding another project parent pom and modules as a dependency, as if they were yours

Tags: java, maven

There is a **project on github**, which has a **parent pom** and **sub modules**.

**I have a project like that too**.

I'd like that code to get **into my editor as if** it was my project, and i could edit and navigate to those files ... but I am not able to successfully do that.

In **my parent** pom, i've tried to add the parent module:

```
<module>./GITHUBROJECT/GITHUBROJECT-core</module>
<module>./GITHUBROJECT/GITHUBROJECT-api</module>
```

and/or just the parent pom path, **hoping** it would read that pom and **resolve all child modules**:

```
<module>./GITHUBROJECT/GITHUBROJECT-api</module>
```

and tried to add all child modules as well.

Then in my "Core" module, I add the dependency, but each time, it seems to always resolve to **jar resources** when using Intellij but for my own projects it always resolve to the **local version**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.GITHUBPROJECT</groupId>
    <artifactId>GITHUBPROJECT</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to configure your IDE to download the source code...if the project offered that on a public repository...

Comment: I've already checked out the project and have the resources.

Comment: [This is an XY Problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Until you clarify by editing your question; what you are trying to accomplish this is most likely the wrong approach.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I am trying to accomplish. The problem is described, and the approaches given are only listed to show what I have already tried. With that said, it turns out Intellij had for some reason put the projects into ignore under settings. Maven was building just fine. So it was not mavens fault.

Answer (score 1):

Maven does not work this way, it does not ever resolve dependencies on **source**. It resolves on **compiled and installed** artifacts regardless of where they are in the parent child hierarchy.

You still have to `mvn install` to get the dependencies to resolve.

> If you are forking a project you need to change the `groupId` at the
>   least so that you can resolve against your fork rather than the
>   original.

Comment: It turns out Intellij had for some reason put the projects into ignore under settings. Maven was building just fine. So it was not mavens fault